# Python Combining strings and printing multiple times

Tags: python, string, printing, combinations

Combining strings and printing multiple times

Let's say I have two lists, and I want to print each element of the first list followed by every element of the second list. For fun, could I also add a word in between those two elements, such as “and”?

Example:

```
firstList = (“cats”, “hats”, “rats”)
secondList = (“dogs”, “frogs”, “logs”)
```

What I want:

```
cats and dogs
cats and frogs
cats and logs
hats and dogs
hats and frogs
hats and logs
rats and dogs
etc...
```

Comment: And what have you tried yourself to do this? Even a simple for loop with [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) would be a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with two `for`s:

```
>>> words = [x + " and " + y for x in firstList for y in secondList]
>>> print(*words, sep="\n")
cats and dogs
cats and frogs
cats and logs
hats and dogs
hats and frogs
hats and logs
rats and dogs
rats and frogs
rats and logs
```

If you wanted to enumerate the list, you could use `enumerate` like this:

```
>>> words = ["{}: {} and {}".format(i, x, y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate([(x, y) for x in firstList for y in secondList])]
>>> print(*words)
0: cats and dogs
1: cats and frogs
2: cats and logs
3: hats and dogs
4: hats and frogs
5: hats and logs
6: rats and dogs
7: rats and frogs
8: rats and logs
```

To make the numbering start at 1, change `"{}: {} and {}".format(i, x, y)` to `"{}: {} and {}".format(i + 1, x, y)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! What if I wanted to number the list?

Answer (score 1):

This should be very easy if I understand what you mean.

```
for item1 in firstlist:
    for item2 in secondlist:
        print(item1+ " and "+item2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as a nested list comprehension

```
items = ['%s and %s' % (a,b) for b in secondList for a in firstList]
```

If you simply want to print the values you can insert a `print` statement

```
ignore = [print('%s and %s' % (a,b)) for b in secondList for a in firstList]
```

Or if you prefer [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
ignore = [print('{0} and {1}'.format(a,b)) for b in secondList for a in firstList]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, another way of doing this is with `itertools.product`.

```
import itertools

firstList = (“cats”, “hats”, “rats”)
secondList = (“dogs”, “frogs”, “logs”)

for item in itertools.product(firstList, secondList):
  print(item[0] + " and " + item[1])
```